# PHP: include или все в один файл?

Tags: include, php, производительность

Здравствуйте! Хотел спросить у разработчиков, у которых возможно был такой опыт! В общем есть идея: писать код модульным образом (каждый модуль в своем файле), и инклудить требуемые модули в итоге в главный файл (к примеру из всех 30 модулей нам нужно только некоторые 5), или такой метод: в конце написания модулей, "склеить" их всех в один файл и сделать один инклуд в главный файл? Для более ясной картины: инклудить 5 требуемых файлов по 100 кб, и с ними работать, или инклудить 1 файл 3000 кб, со всеми сразу склеенными модулями - что быстрее?

Comment: нифига се у вас модули по 100 кб....

Comment: Это я образно =)) Чтобы можно было сравнить цифры!

Comment: вы ещё компилятор для php соберите.

Comment: Автозагрузка классов - это ваше все.

Comment: "Автозагрузка классов - это ваше все." - рассматривал такой вариант... Цитата из документации PHP: "Можно определить функцию __autoload(), которая будет автоматически вызвана при использовании ранее неопределенного класса или интерфейса.". Я думаю это не самый лучший варинат. Если не ошибаюсь, то функция каждый раз листает каталог с файлами, и если нужно опять же инклудит... Это долго, и по моему еще хуже! Прошу, не судите саму идею, а если есть опыт, то скажите что быстрее - инклудить много маленьких файлов, или один большой, но в разы меньший чем общий бьем всех маленьких?

Comment: Я думаю Вам вряд ли кто сможет ответить однозначно. Это Вам лично нужно тестить на том железе, где будет бежать этот код. Какой жесткий диск, оперативка, ОС? А что будет если увеличить нагрузку на сервер? Тут же хренова туча всяких составляющих, но в первую очередь - железо!

Comment: @axejko, если Вы не ошиблись в высказывании

    инклудить много маленьких файлов, или один большой, но в разы меньший чем общий бьем всех маленьких?

(не имели в виду *больший* вместо *меньший* у Вас), то совершенно очевидно, что один меньшего размера "заинклудится" **быстрее**.

Comment: "один меньшего размера "заинклудится" быстрее." - читайте внимательно! "инклудить много маленьких файлов" - это несколько инклудов а не один!

Comment: @axejko, тем более.

Вы пишете, что (чуть другими словами) "*объем большого  файла* **в разы меньше**, *чем общий объем маленьких*".

Так или нет?

--

После этого Вы хотите сказать, что прочесть за раз меньший объем медленнее, чем бОльший объем, открывая много файлов?

--

Или пишите более внятно.

Comment: "Так или нет?" - нет! В моей схеме: или инклудим 100% кода одним инклудом, или к примеру 10 инклудов вместо 30, но инклудится не 100% кода, а только 33%! Разницу понимаете? Прочтите внимательно первый пост!

"После этого Вы хотите сказать, что прочесть за раз меньший объем медленнее, чем бОльший объем, открывая много файлов?" - наоборот! Прочесть за раз больший обьем медленее, чем меньший обьем, открывая много файлов! В этом и заключался вопрос!

Comment: А в комментарии Вы пишете ровно обратное, нежели в первом посте.

Будьте внимательней.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы думаете про оптимизацию на include ? так вы полный путь указывайте и никакого поиска не будет. А вообще в php узкие места не при загрузке файлов обычно, а в первую очередь в логике приложения, во вторую(а часто и в первую) - при обмене с базой данных и в третью - при интерпретации кода, независимо от того в одном это файле или в нескольких, тем более как вы сами заметили не каждый модуль понадобится при каждом запросе, т.е. при использовании схемы "один большой файл", вы будете как минимум производить синтаксическую проверку этого большого файла при каждом запуске.

Comment: Я также более склонен к варианту "Лучше несколько нужных инклудов, чем один большой, но с кучей лишнего кода"! Спасибо!

Comment: да, кстати мой пост не исключает autoload а даже приветствует его.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то такой трюк дает прирост производительности (в особенности в связке с акселератором). require/include в любом случае тратит время на подключение файла (а само время конечно же зависит от HDD и файловой системы), а SSD диски есть не у всех. Например возьмем Zend и посмотрим [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/73273/#comment_2105114), так что в этом есть смысл. Но, не любая архитектура проекта позволяет реализовать подобное.

Comment: "Вообще то такой трюк дает прирост производительности" какой именно? Инклудить несколько мелких, или одним большим?

Comment: Один большой.

Comment: вообще-то в нормальных  осях файлы к которым часто обращаются кэшируются.

Answer (score 2):

Это бред. По сути вы дадите нагрузку больше.

```
<?
include ('5.php'); //в 5пхп $o=2+1;
echo $o.'<br>';
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; //50632
?>

<?
$o=2+1;
echo $o.'<br>';
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; //50192
?>
```

вы можете в магазине сложить всё в один пакет, а можете рассортировать по пакетам, нагрузка только увеличится (время на раскладку + вес пакетов)
другое дело если вы будете из магазина носить небольшие пакеты, т.е. отдельные файлы рега.пхп лк.пхп, но защитить большой пакет легче, чем маленький, смысл у этой функции только в подключении однотипных файлов например конфиг.пхп

а лучше не мучайтесь этой фигней, пишите как удобнее вам, намного больше уходит ввод новых переменных

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите мою статью с исчерпывающим исследованием по теме вопроса.

[Сравнение производительности автозагрузки и объединения классов в один файл](http://seyferseed.ru/ru/php/sravnenie-proizvoditelnosti-avtozagruzki-i-obedineniya-klassov-v-odin-fajl.html)